# How to find or approximate (e.g. using method of steepest descent ) integral?

Tags: cv.complex-variables, integration, approximation-theory

Can you give any advice on how to find or approximate the following integral
$$
F(t,y) = \int_{0}^{y}\frac{i e^{-\frac{3 t^2 \left(x^2+1\right)}{2 \left(9 x^2+1\right)}-i \frac{4 t^2 x}{9 x^2+1}}}{\sqrt{(x-i) (3 x+i)}} dx,
$$
where $t,y \in \mathbb{R}$, $i$ - imaginary unit. More generally, I need to find or approximate the following integral
$$
G(y) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|F(t,y)|^2 dt
$$
(If we talk about the method of steepest descent, I don't see a big parameter $\lambda$ here)